# Constructing a URI in Python?

Tags: python, uri

I'm trying to convert a Java program to Python, and one thing that I am currently stuck on is working with URI's in Python.  I found `urllib.response` in Python, but I'm struggling to figure out how to utilize it.

What I'm trying to do with this URI is obtain user info (particularly username and password), the host and path.  In Java, there are associated methods (`getUserInfo()`, `getHost()`, and `getPath()`) for this, but I'm having trouble finding equivalents for this in Python, even after looking up the `urllib.response` Python documentation.

The equivalent code in Java is:

```
URI dbUri = new URI(env);
username = dbUri.getUserInfo().split(":")[0];
password = dbUri.getUserInfo().split(":")[1];
dbUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://" + dbUri.getHost() + dbUri.getPath();
```

and what would be the appropriate methods that could be used to convert this to Python?

Comment: I posted an answer, but what version of python are you using?  Also what is `env` in your  example?  Just a string ?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.  Originally I was considering using `urllib2` although that is apparently not compatible with that Python verion.  Also `env` is a environment string that is the result of calling `System.getenv()` on the database url path

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you'd want to use something like urllib.parse.urlparse.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

db_url = urlparse(raw_url_string)

username = db_url.username
password = db_url.password
host = db_url.net_loc
path = db_url.path
...
```

You might need to adjust this a bit.  There is a subtle difference between `urlparse` and `urlsplit` regarding parameters.  Then you can use one of the `urlunparse` or `unsplit`.

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```py
from urllib import parse
from urllib.parse import urlsplit

url = 'http://localhost:5432/postgres?user=postgres&password=somePassword'

split_url = urlsplit(url)

hostname = split_url.netloc
path = split_url.path

params = dict(parse.parse_qsl(split_url.query))
username = params['user']
password = params['password']

db_url = "jdbc:postgresql://" + hostname + path
print(db_uri)
```

---

**Output**

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
```